# Перебор массива vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Нужно сделать перебор массива "game.bets[0].is_win" Всего 20, нужно что бы через цикл как то перебирался и выводился, что бы потом можно было его вставить

```
<span class="profile-stats_maxwin">{{ game.bets[0].is_win }}</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

```
<span v-for="bet in game.bets" :key="bet.id" class="profile-stats_maxwin">{{bet.is_win}}</span>
```

Comment: спасибо, а как их сложить?